# Which is faster for a tcp connection?

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

A quick question:

I'm sending data over the network using boost:asio (tcp).  Which would be faster:  using a stream buffer, or, divide and send data as packets manually?

In particular, what if the size of data to be transferred is typically over 100mb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Faster" can mean 2 different things:

1. Minimum latency. This mean minimize time between packet data generating and receiving by client. In this case its "faster" to make packets manually on socket that have TCP_NODELAY option.
2. Maximize bandwidth speed. This mean you want to transfer data (e.g. a file) with maximum Mb/s speed. In this case its better to disable TCP_NODELAY and send data [sendfile(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile).

Now about boost::asio. This for minimum latency you setup TCP_NODELAY option too ([example for this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html)). For maximum total transfer speed its better to turn off this option and use streambuffer, or take native handle via **native_handle()** and use sendfile on it (in this case its more work to make it "good" async need to be done).

Comment: Thanks.  This answers a lot of the questions I had regarding performance.  I'll setup TCP_NODELAY and use a streambuffer.

Answer (score 0):

The more you overthink this the more you will get in the way of TCP doing its job and the worse it will perform. Just stream the data, using as large buffers as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think I'll go the buffer route.